# PayPal IPN delivery status Retrying and HTTP response code 500

Tags: php, pdo, paypal, paypal-ipn

I am trying to implement the IPN Listener from PayPal.

This is my listener:

```
<?php namespace Listener;

require('PaypalIPN.php');

use PaypalIPN;

$ipn = new PaypalIPN();

// Use the sandbox endpoint during testing.
$verified = $ipn->verifyIPN();
if ($verified) {
    /*
     * Process IPN
     * A list of variables is available here:
     * https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNandPDTVariables/
     */

    // Buyer info
    $payer_email = $_POST['payer_email'];
    $payer_id = $_POST['payer_id'];

    // Payment info
    $payment_amount = $_POST['mc_gross'];
    $payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
    $payment_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
    $item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
    $item_number = $_POST['item_number'];
    
    // Merchant Info
    $txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
    $receiver_email = $_POST['receiver_email'];
   
    // Custom
    $custom = $_POST['custom'];

    if($payment_amount >= '10') {
        // Donation is $10 or higher, so let's add 10% to the coins.
        $coins = $payment_amount*1.1;
    }
    elseif($payment_amount >= '50') {
        // Donation is $50 or higher, so let's add 20% to the coins.
        $coins = $payment_amount*1.2;
    }
    elseif($payment_amount >= '100') {
        // Donation is $100 or higher, so let's add 25% to the coins.
        $coins = $payment_amount*1.25;
    }
    else {
        // Donation is less than $10, no bonus.
        $coins = $payment_amount;
    }
    
    $acc = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=Host;Database=DB", "USR", "Pass");

    $check = $acc->prepare("SELECT * FROM Cash WHERE ID = :account");
    $check->bindParam(':account', $custom, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $check->execute();

    if($check->rowCount()) {
        $add = $acc->prepare("UPDATE Cash SET Cash = Cash + :coins WHERE ID = :account");
        $add->bindParam(':coins', $coins, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $add->bindParam(':account', $custom, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $add->execute();
    }

    // Log the donation 
    $acc = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=Host;Database=DB", "USR", "PASS");

    $method = 'PayPal';
    $query = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO logs (Account, Amount, Coins, Method, Date) VALUES (:account, :amount, :coins, :method, GETDATE())");
    $query->bindParam(':account', $custom, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindParam(':amount', $payment_amount, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->bindParam(':coins', $coins, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->bindParam(':method', $method, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->execute();

}

// Reply with an empty 200 response to indicate to paypal the IPN was received correctly.
header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
```

This is the IPN class:

```
<?php

class PaypalIPN
{
    /** @var bool Indicates if the sandbox endpoint is used. */
    private $use_sandbox = false;
    /** @var bool Indicates if the local certificates are used. */
    private $use_local_certs = true;

    /** Production Postback URL */
    const VERIFY_URI = 'https://ipnpb.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr';
    /** Sandbox Postback URL */
    const SANDBOX_VERIFY_URI = 'https://ipnpb.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr';

    /** Response from PayPal indicating validation was successful */
    const VALID = 'VERIFIED';
    /** Response from PayPal indicating validation failed */
    const INVALID = 'INVALID';

    /**
     * Sets the IPN verification to sandbox mode (for use when testing,
     * should not be enabled in production).
     * @return void
     */
    public function useSandbox()
    {
        $this->use_sandbox = false;
    }

    /**
     * Sets curl to use php curl's built in certs (may be required in some
     * environments).
     * @return void
     */
    public function usePHPCerts()
    {
        $this->use_local_certs = false;
    }

    /**
     * Determine endpoint to post the verification data to.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPaypalUri()
    {
        if ($this->use_sandbox) {
            return self::SANDBOX_VERIFY_URI;
        } else {
            return self::VERIFY_URI;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Verification Function
     * Sends the incoming post data back to PayPal using the cURL library.
     *
     * @return bool
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public function verifyIPN()
    {
        if ( ! count($_POST)) {
            throw new Exception("Missing POST Data");
        }

        $raw_post_data = file_get_contents('php://input');
        $raw_post_array = explode('&', $raw_post_data);
        $myPost = array();
        foreach ($raw_post_array as $keyval) {
            $keyval = explode('=', $keyval);
            if (count($keyval) == 2) {
                // Since we do not want the plus in the datetime string to be encoded to a space, we manually encode it.
                if ($keyval[0] === 'payment_date') {
                    if (substr_count($keyval[1], '+') === 1) {
                        $keyval[1] = str_replace('+', '%2B', $keyval[1]);
                    }
                }
                $myPost[$keyval[0]] = urldecode($keyval[1]);
            }
        }

        // Build the body of the verification post request, adding the _notify-validate command.
        $req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
        $get_magic_quotes_exists = false;
        if (function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc')) {
            $get_magic_quotes_exists = true;
        }
        foreach ($myPost as $key => $value) {
            if ($get_magic_quotes_exists == true && get_magic_quotes_gpc() == 1) {
                $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
            } else {
                $value = urlencode($value);
            }
            $req .= "&$key=$value";
        }

        // Post the data back to PayPal, using curl. Throw exceptions if errors occur.
        $ch = curl_init($this->getPaypalUri());
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 6);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);

        // This is often required if the server is missing a global cert bundle, or is using an outdated one.
        if ($this->use_local_certs) {
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO,  "cacert.pem");
        }
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            'User-Agent: PHP-IPN-Verification-Script',
            'Connection: Close',
        ));
        $res = curl_exec($ch);
        if ( ! ($res)) {
            $errno = curl_errno($ch);
            $errstr = curl_error($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
            throw new Exception("cURL error: [$errno] $errstr");
        }

        $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
        $http_code = $info['http_code'];
        if ($http_code != 200) {
            throw new Exception("PayPal responded with http code $http_code");
        }

        curl_close($ch);

        // Check if PayPal verifies the IPN data, and if so, return true.
        if ($res == self::VALID) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

What I am doing wrong? If I check the IPN history I see that the delivery status is always set to `Retrying` and the HTTP response is `500`

I already added the listener URL to my Merchant Paypal Account (https://example.com/paypal_listener.php)

**UPDATE:**

After many retries, the status has been changed to `Sent` and HTTP response to `200`. The only thing that is not working, is that my Database is not getting updated, it seems like I am not receiving any data. I am not sure what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

> I am not sure what's happening.

The reason you are not sure what's happening, is you are not logging what is happening.

In your script, you need to add logging output to a file. Log the message contents the IPN you receive. Log each branch of resolution in your script. Log everything that happens, including whether it was verified and including whether you connected to the database. Then debug the result.

Comment: When I test the listener URL in the IPN Simulator, I get a success message. But when I do it on production, it just keeps Retrying with an error of 500.

Comment: All of which needs to be debugged on your server, so that you can find out why it is replying with an HTTP 500 Internal Server Error.

Comment: And how exactly I can log the errors? Sorry, this is the first time I try to implement the PayPal IPN to a website.

Comment: Search for "php write to log file" or similar. Log everything I mentioned above.